# Ruby statement with embedded SQL INSERT - Syntax error

Tags: sql, ruby, exception, insert

I have the following Ruby script: It creates a database, reads a csv file and inserts each row into the database.

```
 require "sqlite3"
 require "csv"
 require "pp"

begin
 db = SQLite::Database.new("myDB.db")
 db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYTABLE(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  stations TEXT, dayparts TEXT, age TEXT, rtg DOUBLE, reach DOUBLE")

 myData  = {}
 CSV.foreach("test_file.csv", :headers=>true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => :all)              
 do |row|
  row.to_hash.each do |key, value|
   mydata[key.to_sym] = value
  end
 db.execute("INSERT INTO myDB(stations, dayparts, age, rtg, reach) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", 
 myDATA[:stations], myData[:dayparts], myData[:age], myData[:rtg], mydata[:dlyrch000])
 end

rescue SQLite3::Exception => e
  puts "Exception occured"
  puts e

ensure
  db.close if db
end
```

When I run this script with static data. that is this line:

```
 db.execute("INSERT INTO myDB(stations, dayparts, age, rtg, reach) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", 
   myDATA[:stations], myData[:dayparts], myData[:age], myData[:rtg], mydata[:dlyrch000])
```

is replaced by this:

```
 db.execute("INSERT INTO myDB(stations, dayparts, age, rtg, reach) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", 
 test, test, 33, .8989, .23434)
```

A database is created with this data.

But when I try this script as above it throws an exception:

```
 syntax error, unexpected ",", expecting ')' ... rtg, reach) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",  
 ---> myData [:stations], myData[....
```

etc.

I have tried different options but cannot seem to get around this. Can someone please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three syntax errors I can see.

- The `CREATE TABLE` SQL statement as a missing close parenthesis before the closing quote. It should look like

  ```
  db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYTABLE(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      stations TEXT, dayparts TEXT, age TEXT, rtg DOUBLE, reach DOUBLE)")
  ```
- The block for `CSV.foreach` has to start on the same line as the closing parenthesis for the method call, like this

  ```
  CSV.foreach("test_file.csv", :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => :all) do |row|
    ...
  enc
  ```
- The database constructor uses `SQLite` when it should be `SQLite3`. Like this

  ```
  db = SQLite3::Database.new("myDB.db")
  ```

I can't see anything wrong with the part of your code that is raising an error, but I presume you aren't showing the current version of your program as it is a long way from getting as far as that.

Comment: I added some code above so it should be clear what is causing the exception. Thx for your help